# Two images side by side and text on it

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add images as a background and I need to write text on both. The problem which I am facing is the gap b/w two images. I don't know why it's showing me gap.

```
<div class='imgcontainer'>
    <div id="first"> <h4 > SYRIAN CRISIS </h4>
        <p > We are organizing a conference in April 2016 on
            water and humanitarian aspects of the Syrian crisis.
            Click <a href="projectc.html">here</a> to learn about the crisis and our
            conference.</p></div>
    <div id="second"><h2>SMALLHOLDER</h2><h3> AGRICULTURE</h3>
        <p>We are organizing a workshop in April 2016 on smallholder irrigation in Sub-Saharan Africa. Click here
            to learn about the challenge of agriculture in the
            region and our workshop.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="clear"></div>
</div>






#first {
    width: 680px;
    background: url('../images/banner-img1.jpg');
    float: left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 440px;
    margin: auto;
}
#second {
    width: 650px;
    float: right;
    background: url('../images/banner-img2.jpg');
    height: 440px;
    margin: auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

}
```

Comment: you floated the divs left and right. if your screen is bigger than the sum of the widths of those divs, you WILL get a gap.

Comment: May I know how can I fix this?

Comment: Yes, try either floating both left, or setting each div's display to inline-block

Comment: Don't float the divs left and right

Comment: @TonyDuffill Thanks it works. I used display to inline-block. I remove width and height. The problem I am facing now they attached with each other end to end that;'s fine but they are giving extra space on the right side of screen.

Comment: In that case put back the width on each div - preferably using percent. But here's a tip --- you may find it necessary that the total percentages add up to 99, not 100, to avoid overflow.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your screen is wider than `680px` + `650px` = `1330px`

First div is aligned to the left, second one to the right, both have fixed widths.. if your browser width is > `1330px` you'll have a gap between this divs

Comment: When I am putting more px then one image is going down.

Comment: what should I do to fix it then? yeah I gave container of the website to1350px

Comment: Use percentage instead of pixels

Comment: Giving 50% width to both creates gap too. if I give more than 50% one image goes down.

Comment: Use your code inspector in google chrome to analyze what causes this gap

Comment: I did. when I removed no repeat then the repeat image was covering the gap.

Comment: Should I use stretch property of CSS3?

Comment: I don't think so.. can you replicate the bug on https://jsfiddle.net/ and post the link

Comment: It's working fine there. I think some bugs in my other code. Seems difficult to fix.

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/animenon/pen/RaBjoB)

CSS:

```
.imgcontainer {
  position: relative;
}

.right,
.left {
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}

.right {
  right: 0;
}

.left {
  left: 0;
}

#first {
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  background: url('../images/banner-img1.jpg');
  left: 0;
}

#second {
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  background: url('../images/banner-img2.jpg');
  right: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class='imgcontainer'>
  <div id="first">
    <h4> SYRIAN CRISIS </h4>
    <p> We are organizing a conference in April 2016 on water and humanitarian aspects of the Syrian crisis. Click <a href="projectc.html">here</a> to learn about the crisis and our conference.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="second">
    <h2>SMALLHOLDER</h2>
    <h3> AGRICULTURE</h3>
    <p>We are organizing a workshop in April 2016 on smallholder irrigation in Sub-Saharan Africa. Click here to learn about the challenge of agriculture in the region and our workshop.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: didn't works for me. Causing problem to whole website